# What is the safest and quietest practical lightweight electric saw to cut 2x4 to use inside an apartment?

Tags: wood, noise, cutting, saw

I have a miter saw but that thing is loud. Same with the circular saw. Moreover, while the miter saw can be used on the ground with not even a table, the circular saw is too dangerous without a full workbench.

A table saw, even mini one, is too big, expensive, and also too loud. It needs to be handheld. Obviously, chainsaw is not the answer either.

Of course, the quietest is a simple hand saw. Unfortunately, it's also too much work and takes too long. I want something electric.

This brought me to the reciprocating saw. It could be used easily with a couple portable sawhorses or even just clamped to the table.

Handheld jigsaw might be the same.

For safety, of course awareness, alertness, glasses, earmuffs, gloves, and common sense will all be used. Still, some tools are less safe than others without a full workshop. I'm also thinking of building a small portable workbench.

I don't want to disturb the neighbors or cause any alerts with the apartment complex. So, what is the best, quietest, safest, and easiest electric saw to use to cut 2x4 without a full workshop or full work bench?

Comment: don't want to disturb the neighbors = no reciprocating saw of any kind

Comment: Lesser sounds like a drill will not cause a problem but extreme sounds like a circular saw are too loud. It's my understanding that a jigsaw or reciprocating saw is quieter than a circular saw?

Comment: Noise is also exponential with time. 4 hours of a light sawing noise is a greater annoyance and would attract more unwanted attention than 10 minutes of 5-second cuts here and there with a power tool in the middle of the day. Moreover, I think you underestimate the noise and vibration of a hand saw going on for hours and hours.

Comment: That's better than straining to hear wtf you're doing with a handsaw, and then it goes *clunk* every half hour.

Comment: @Mazura I agree that is completely my point lol, a hand saw could get really annoying to neighbors, and you make a good point about the steady *clunk* after each cut lol

Comment: Have you considered cutting everything in the parking lot, then bringing it in for assembly? (Failing that, I vote jigsaw.)

Comment: No that would be worse. There are no walls to shield the sound and now it is obvious who it is making the sound. Moreover, now you have to lug everything up and down three flights of stairs, which, after being built, may be too heavy for you. Moreover, it would not even be allowed anyway. Not to mention the challenge of trying to clean up the sawdust.

Comment: However if you did it in a remote area that would be a great way to have zero noise, but two problems: Finding a remote area where people aren't going to bother you can be difficult unless you live in the country, which isn't the case if you're looking for a solution. It also may not be possible. And gas to drive that far is a serious cost. I don't know of anywhere I could go where it would be safe to cut without being bothered. My own apartment is the best place, especially if I use the quieter tool, and use a power tool where the noise is quick, and do it at the right time of day.

Comment: IPS solution: find out when the neighbors both next to you, and below you, aren't home.

Comment: @Mazura Not only those neighbors but also the neighbors to the side, the neighbors in other adjacent buildings, and the maintenance crew which drives by in the golf cart every 30 minutes to an hour during business days and times. In other words, if I waiting until the time it's a ghost town the time is never, so it needs to be quiet enough not to attract attention.

Comment: @user2966384 How about bribing the neighbours with, e.g., chocolates to find out when they won't be in and thus won't mind the noise?

Comment: I believe the battery powered version of any power tool will be quieter. You also have to consider that some of the noise is from the work piece and work bench transmitting vibration to the floor. A pad under your work piece as well as your workbench will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider a scroll saw. Mine is a good bit quieter than my jigsaw and the base provides decent stability for good cuts.

Comment: scroll saw is interesting, hadn't thought of it. Similar price range to the rest, although closer to miter saw prices. Quieter, yes, bulkier though, and is that practical for cutting 2x4? I thought scroll saw was best for fine detail work.

Comment: It will cut them, but it is not designed for that purpose. I think it might be a practical option with the limitations you pose in the question.

Comment: But would you say that a handheld jigsaw or reciprocating saw would be better suited than a scroll saw for sawing through 2x4?

Comment: Reciprocating saw would work quite well, but the cut would not be very clean probably and those are pretty loud. Jigsaw is louder than a scroll saw and vibration would cause extra annoyance with neighbors in my opinion. They do make mini-circular saws, but I've never used one, so I don't know how loud the are. If this were me, I would use a good hand saw.

Comment: a handheld jigsaw? You sure you're talking about the same item? Maybe you're talking about a big table jigsaw. I'm talking about a small handheld one.

Comment: https://toolcrib.com/blog/2008/01/power-tool-decibel-levels-could-be-hurting-your-ears/

Comment: Thank you, from that link it appears the Milwaukee handheld jigsaw is 101 DB. lease note that the Ryobi jigsaw latest model is brushless which should be quieter but at least now we have a ballpark. An online forum says don't use it on low for cutting but you can use on medium for noise. Although they are talking about the older brushed model from 2015.

Comment: Probably not what I will do since I don't want to buy one, but accepted since you thought outside the box and gave me new info I didn't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

jigsaw.

but really i think you underestimate how easy it is to cut through dimensional lumber with a sharp handsaw.

Comment: Easier than a hand saw? That's what matters here. I'm not building a house just smaller projects.

Comment: a jigsaw will definitely be slower. If you run a jigsaw to fast, the blade deflects and yields very unsquare cuts. A handsaw with miter box is fast. After some practice you won't even need the miter box.

Comment: it's a lot more effort to use a hand saw undeniably, and I am dubious about your claim that " a hand saw is faster than a jigsaw". Any evidence to back that up?

Comment: @user2966384 - You're pushing (down) too hard. Let the saw do the work, and submit yourself to the fact that you will bring the saw back and forth about a hundred times to cut a 2x4 - which should take you less than 20 seconds.

Comment: 20 second is dubious, 100 repetitions is extremely repetitive, even 30 seconds is much slower than 5 to 10 seconds for a power tool and dramatically more effort even if you're barely pushing down. tens of thousands of sawing motions is a serious workout.

Comment: A scroll saw cutting is quieter, but the machine vibrations will translate through the floor much worse than a jig saw. Also the cuts won't be straight. A handsaw is faster than jigsaw for the same quality cut - you need to go very slow with a jigsaw to get any quality. Also, the workpiece should always be supported no matter what tool you use so you should never have a clunk of piece falling to the floor except for the roughest of operations. You asked for fastest quietest and safest electrical solution... Which is jigsaw.

Comment: I would say 20 seconds is accurate, 100 motions far too high an estimate tho. What you don't consider is the weight of the power tool - more weight less reps :) you might also be overestimating the number of cuts you will need for small projects.

Comment: No evidence, since I won't be posting a video. I'm sorry I don't have any studies I can reference, just ten years of my experience with all sorts of power and hand tools.

Comment: @user2966384 - "100" is an over estimate, used for literal illustrative purposes. That's what it should *look* like; not being able to count it because you're going so fast. If you can't go that fast, **you're pushing too hard.** Pretend it's a hacksaw; if you push too hard it just stops. You go fast AF, with very little pressure. I know, it sounds like work. *It is.*

Comment: @Mazura it's all work. woodwork lol.

Comment: @Mazura Exactly, like you said, it seems like a lot of work and *it is a lot of work* which is **exactly** why I **do not** want to use a hand saw.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is a legitimate answer, but I'd reconsider a hand saw.  Depending on what works well for you, and what you need to do with the saw.  I'd try a pull saw, very easy to use and makes a nice clean cut, almost anyone can get good results with this type of saw.  They don't bind and they are very easy to get started.  The way the blade is made, there is not much set to the teeth, so it takes less energy to cut.  Lubricate the surface of the metal by spraying it with some WD40 or whatever, as long as you're not concerned about a little oil on the end grain.

[image: shark pull saw]

Some people try to use a hand saw just like they use a circular saw and get poor results.  The sawhorse setup usually used with a circular saw is not ideal with a hand saw.  Sawhorses or a pickup truck tailgate are higher than you'd want for use with a hand saw.

A traditional saw bench is about knee high, that's a good height so you can get your knee on the board.  If the word "ergonomic" had been invented back when saw benches were commonly used, they would have been called ergonomic.  You'll want to look for or set up something approximately that height.  No clamps needed, your body weight on your knee is the clamp.

[image: Christopher Schwarz - saw bench]

Usually you can improvise and find something that's a good height, for example the bench seat of a picnic table is usually just right.

Comment: No I have a good handsaw already but I don't like the time and effort it takes over electric.

Comment: Some people can't use hand tools.  Millennials.

Comment: I can use hand tools. Not a millennial. It is still far more effort and time than power tools. Not practical. You're right though [many/most] millennials can't do much :P

Comment: Yes this kind of saw is a great example, much quieter than any motorized tool when you let the tool do the work.

Comment: @user2966384 - I promise you a good hand saw used properly is quite fast, and you don't have to be Hercules.  It will probably cut faster than a jigsaw now that I think about it.  By the time you clamp a 2x4 so you can cut it with a reciprocating saw, I'll be half way through with a hand saw.  I am even going to edit my answer.

Comment: I already told you I HAVE A GOOD HAND SAW AND IT IS TOO SLOW AND I DON'T WANT TO USE IT, WHICH IS WHY I WANT TO USE A POWER TOOL, your promise is BROKEN.

Comment: the issue is really that there is nothing powered that will give a good quality cut both quieter and faster than a good sharp handsaw. The jigsaw comes close, but is still quiet loud and for the same quality cut, not faster.

Comment: @user2966384 - I have a feeling you should use a circular saw, it will be the second loudest thing on your job site :)

Answer (score 0):

A reciprocating saw or jig saw isn't going to give you a very good quality cut.  How much cutting do you expect to do?  Maybe plan on doing it in the middle of the day when noise is less objectionable.  Or talk to the neighbors and see what times are reasonable for them ... in case somebody works nights or such.

You might also look into a local makerspace or other shared workspace.  More space, better tools, mentors, etc.  I've done woodworking in an apartment ... it's not great.

Comment: Well true but I can sand down the edges. There are times when a miter or circular saw can be used, but I am referring to the other times rather than putting projects on hold until an "optimal" time or not even doing volumes of project due to noise worries.

Comment: As for the shared workspace, I don't do enough or frequently enough to warrant buying some membership for a few hundred dollars a month. Even $50 per month would be a waste of money if it existed that low and it doesn't. $2 per month would be worth it in value, not possible. Shared workspaces are basically office space prices at like $500+ per month, zero point in that. Plus, then I'd still have to transport what I made back home, completely pointless.

Comment: No idea what the market looks like in general, but the Pikes Peak Makerspace is about $600/year IIRC.  Not really oriented toward woodworking though, with the exception of the big CNC router.

Comment: $600/yr ($50 per month) is kind of pointless for infrequent work and then still have to transport the large items back to the apartment, not to mention it only exists in Colorado although there may be others. It would only be practical at $2 per month, $5 at the most, which isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Buy the right blade for your circular saw first. Technology has come a long way, always keep it sharp!!
2. A soft start takes the bang out of start up...huge difference.
3. An electric brake helps heaps. You don't get that wind down end noise which is useless noise time really.
4. Buy a blade stiffener..well worth the money.